# Haskell: Between a list and a tuple

Tags: list, math, haskell, functional-programming, tuples

I want a function `+++` that adds two mathematical vectors.

I could implement vectors as `[x, y, z]` and use:

```
(+++) :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(+++) = zipWith (+)
```

And thus accomodate any *n*-dimensional vector (so this would work for `[x, y]` too).

Or I could implement vectors as `(x, y, z)` and use:

```
type Triple a = (a, a, a)

merge :: (a -> b -> c) -> Triple a -> Triple b -> Triple c
merge f (a, b, c) (x, y, z) = (f a x, f b y, f c z)

(+++) :: (Num a) => Triple a -> Triple a -> Triple a
(+++) = merge (+)
```

Of course this is slightly more complex but it when I implement all the other vector functions, that is irrelevant (50 lines instead of 40).

The problem with the list approach is that I can add a 2D vector with a 3D vector. In that case, `zipWith` would simply chop off the 3D vector's `z` component. While that might make sense (more likely it should expand the 2D vector to `[x, y, 0]`), for other functions I'm thinking it could be problematic to have either happen silently. The problem with the tuple approach is it limits the vector to 3 components.

Intuitively, I would think that it would make more sense to represent vectors as `(x, y, z)`, since a mathematical vector has a fixed number of components and it doesn't really make sense to cons (prepend) a component to a vector.

On the other hand, although it's very unlikely that I will need anything other than 3D vectors, it doesn't seem quite right to limit it to that.

I guess what I want is functions that take two lists of equal length, or better, functions that operate on tuples of arbitrary size.

Any *suggestions*, in terms of practicality, scalability, elegance, etc.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220953/does-haskell-have-variadic-functions-tuples

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but you might want to take a look at the [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) package.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Landei's and leftaroundabout's answers are good (thanks to you both), and I guess I should have realized that this wouldn't be as simple as I'd hoped. Trying to do either of the options I suggested makes for complex code, which woudn't be a problem in itself except that it seems the user code wouldn't be very pretty to look at either.

I think I've decided to go with tuples and stick with 3-dimension only vectors, simply because it seems more semantically correct than using lists. I'm ending up re-implenting `map`, `zipWith`, `sum` and others for triples, though. I want to stick with simplicity—I feel as though if I had a compelling argument to think of vectors as lists, then that solution would work better (provided I make sure I don't mix dimensions)… When I actually use the vectors, though, functions will take a 3d vector as an argument, not one of variable dimensions, and `Num a => [a]` can't enforce that.

Comment: use `Data.Vector` from the `vector` package or `ACVector` package which has 3D vectors.  These libraries have defined helper functions already, saving you time and energy.

Comment: The code for a library might be complex, but you can hide it pretty well from the user using things like `type` definitions and convenience methods.

Answer (score 21):

You can use type level programming. First we need to make every natural number a separate type. Following Peano's definition of the natural numbers, `Z` is `0`, and `S x` is `x + 1`

```
data Z = Z
data S a = S a

class Nat a
instance Nat Z
instance (Nat a) => Nat (S a)
```

Now we can use a type `Vec` to simply wrap a list, but to keep track of its size by using `Nat`. For this, we use the [smart constructors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors) `nil` and `<:>` (so you shouldn't export the data constructor `Vec` from your module)

```
data Vec a = Vec a [Int]

nil = Vec Z []

infixr 5 <:>
x <:> (Vec n xs) = Vec (S n) (x:xs)
```

Now we can define an `add` function, which requires that two vectors have the same `Nat`:

```
add :: Nat a => Vec a -> Vec a -> Vec a
add (Vec n xs) (Vec _ ys) = Vec n (zipWith (+) xs ys)
```

Now you have a vector type with length information:

```
toList (Vec _ xs) = xs
main = print $ toList $ add (3 <:> 4 <:> 2 <:> nil) (10 <:> 12 <:> 0 <:> nil)
```

Of course having vectors with different length here will cause a compile error.

This is the easy to understand version, there are shorter, more efficient and/or more convenient solutions.

Comment: I wonder the "more efficient and/or more convenient" solutions, does anyone care to give some pointers?

Comment: I think you can get similar effects with `HList`s: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HList/0.2.3/doc/html/Data-HList-HListPrelude.html

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to put the `+++` operator in a type class, and make the various tuple sizes instances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}   -- needed to make tuples type class instances

class Additive v where
  (+++) :: v -> v -> v

instance (Num a) => Additive (a,a) where
  (x,y) +++ (ξ,υ)  =  (x+ξ, y+υ)
instance (Num a) => Additive (a,a,a) where
  (x,y,z) +++ (ξ,υ,ζ)  =  (x+ξ, y+υ, z+ζ)
...
```

This way, variable-length tuples may be added but it will be ensured at compile-time that both sides always have the same length.

---

Generalizing this to use a function like your `merge` in the actual type class is also possible: in this case, you need to specify the class instance as a type constructor (like the list monad).

```
class Mergable q where
  merge :: (a->b->c) -> q a -> q b -> q c

instance Mergable Triple where
  merge f (x,y,z) (ξ,υ,ζ) = (f x ξ, f y υ, f z ζ)
```

and then simply

```
(+++) :: (Mergable q, Num a) => q a -> q b -> q c
+++ = merge (+)
```

Unfortunately, this does not quite work, because type synonyms may not be partially evaluated. You need to make `Triple` a newtype instead, like

```
newtype Triple a = Triple(a,a,a)
```

and then

```
instance Mergable Triple where
  merge f (Triple(x,y,z)) (Triple((ξ,υ,ζ)) = Triple(f x ξ, f y υ, f z ζ)
```

which is of course not quite as nice to look at.

Comment: @VladtheImpala: perhaps you prefer [Japanese](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4824/2183)? — Seriously, what's wrong with calling local variables greek names? It forces nobody to type them in their own code, if you know the greek alphabet it makes sense to associate e.g. z with zeta, and if you don't it makes little difference compared to arbitrary latin letters.

Answer (score 1):

As OP wanted a more lightweight approach, I would use associated types.

```
class VecMath a b where
    type Res a b :: *
    (+++) :: a -> b -> Res a b

instance Num a => VecMath (a,a,a) (a,a,a) where
    type Res (a,a,a) (a,a,a) = (a,a,a)
    (x1,y1,z1) +++ (x2,y2,z2) = (x1+x2, y1+y2, z1+z2)

instance Num a => VecMath (a,a) (a,a,a) where
    type Res (a,a) (a,a,a) = (a,a,a)
    (x1,y1) +++ (x2,y2,z) = (x1+x2, y1+y2, z)

instance Num a => VecMath (a,a,a) (a,a) where
    type Res (a,a) (a,a,a) = (a,a,a)
    -- (+++) analog
instance Num a => VecMath (a,a) (a,a) where
    type Res (a,a) (a,a) = (a,a)
    -- ...
```

`Res` is a type function, here essentially resulting in the 'bigger' type of it's arguments. The advantage is that you still can work with plain old tuples, as if `VecMath` didn't exist. The dark side is the exponential explosion of instances you have to write, if you consider adding new types to the domain of `Res`.
For more information see [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_families).