# Haskell, is it possible to create a curry function that can curry any number of tuple elements

Tags: haskell, currying, partial-application

The current curry function takes a function accepting a tuple of 2 elements and allows the resulting function to be curried or partially applied.

```
let x = curry (\(x, y) -> x + y)
x 1 2 -- 3
```

Is it possible to create a curry function that can deal with functions that have N elements in their tuples?

I tried creating it, but I'm not sure about 1: type signature, and 2: how to reverse the parameters.

```
curryN f 0 = f
curryN f n = \a -> (curryN (f) (n-1)) a

curryN (\(x, y, z) -> x + y + z) 3
-- I assume it looks something like: \a -> (\a -> (\a -> (f) a) a) a but I'm not sure
```

OR

```
curryN f 0 =  f
curryN f n = curryN (\a - > f a) (n -1)
```

On a side note, can such a function then discover the number of elements rather than needing to be told what the number is?

Comment: If `n` is statically known, (e.g. with a proxy or type-level numeral)  this is a nice exercise for type families. See e.g. [Uncurry for n-ary functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843224/uncurry-for-n-ary-functions). Using nested pairs instead of n-tuples should allow for a recursive solution.

Comment: Not in standard Haskell (e.g. Haskell 98 or Haskell 2010).

Comment: Related: https://ro-che.info/articles/2013-01-29-generic-uncurry

Comment: @chi's comment basically answers this question. To un-jargon it a little bit, the problem is that the second argument to `curryN` is not a value-level number (`2 :: Int`) but a *type-level* number. (The distinction is a little bit like that between run-time and compile-time.) Writing `curryN` therefore requires advanced type system features. For a different, practical solution, see the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220953/does-haskell-have-variadic-functions-tuples).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, although I would appreciate if you could post an answer so I can accept an answer to this question. Would be great for an answer to show different ways of achieving this, including the practical way @ChristianConkle and the type family way.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate either way. @chi is one of the answerers on the n-ary question; if you want some further explanation, you could leave  a comment there. It might make sense to edit "currying" into the title of the question I linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways to implement such function is to use [GHC.Generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics). With this approach we don't even need to pass a number of parameters (or tuple size).
This works because there is an instance of `Generic` defined for tuples which effectively converts a tuple into tree structure (of type `Rep a`) which we can then traverse from right to left (using continuation passing style here) generating curried function along the way and packing the values of those parameters into identical `Rep a` structure which then converted into tuple with `to` function and passed to the original un-curried function-parameter. This code uses only type-level tree of parameters (`from` function is not used) since we produce the tuple rather then receiving it.
The only limitation of this approach is that `Generic` is defined only for up to eight-element tuple.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, MultiParamTypeClasses,
  FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances,
  TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import GHC.Generics


-- | class for `curryN` function
class CurryN t r where
    type CurriedN t r :: *
    curryN :: (t -> r) -> CurriedN t r

-- | Implementation of curryN which uses GHC.Generics
instance (Generic t, GCurryN (Rep t) r) => CurryN t r where
    type CurriedN t r = GCurriedN (Rep t) r
    curryN f = gcurryN (f . to)

-- | Auxiliary class for generic implementation of `curryN`
--   Generic representation of a tuple is a tree of its elements
--   wrapped into tuple constructor representation
--   We need to fold this tree constructing a curried function
--   with parameters corresponding to every elements of the tuple
class GCurryN f r where
    type GCurriedN f r :: *
    gcurryN :: (f p -> r) -> GCurriedN f r

-- | This matches tuple definition
--   Here we extract tree of tuple parameters and use other instances to "fold" it into function
instance (GCurryN f r) => GCurryN (D1 e1 (C1 e2 f)) r where
    type GCurriedN (D1 e1 (C1 e2 f)) r = GCurriedN f r
    gcurryN c = gcurryN (\t -> c (M1 (M1 t)))

-- | A node of the tree (combines at least two parameters of the tuple)
instance (GCurryN b r, GCurryN a (GCurriedN b r)) => GCurryN (a :*: b) r where
    type GCurriedN (a :*: b) r = GCurriedN a (GCurriedN b r)
    gcurryN c = gcurryN (\a -> gcurryN (\b -> c (a :*: b)))

-- | A leaf of the tree (a single tuple parameter)
instance GCurryN (S1 NoSelector (Rec0 a)) r where
    type GCurriedN (S1 NoSelector (Rec0 a)) r = a -> r
    gcurryN c = \a -> c $ M1 (K1 a)


-- Examples of usage
t2 = curryN (uncurry (&&))

t3 = curryN (\(a,b,c) -> a + b + c)

t4 = curryN (\(a,b,c,d) -> ((a , b) , (c , d)))

tf = curryN (\(f,a,xs) -> foldr f a xs)

t5 = curryN (\(a,b,c,d,e) -> (a ++ b , c - d, not e))

t7 = curryN (\(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7) -> a7)
```